# Run method after capturing invoice

Tags: invoice

What is the difference between the `sales_order_invoice_register`, `sales_order_invoice_save_after` and `sales_order_place_after` events?

I'd like to run a method after the payment capture for the invoice is carried out. Which event is best to hook to?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 9):

`sales_order_invoice_save_after` is triggered when the `sales_order_invoice` object is saved.

`sales_order_invoice_register` is an event in the class `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice` method `register`. This method is used to assign data about the invoice to the order.

I would suggest going with `sales_order_invoice_save_after` or, maybe even better: `sales_order_invoice_pay` since that method is called when the invoice is payed.

Comment: Be careful when using `sales_order_invoice_save_after`. It is triggered everytime, so if the invoice already exists, it is triggered when adding data or whatever. So check carefully that the invoice is in a state you want to have it to run whatever you want to run. You don't know whether the invoice is new. What you can do is adding a flag in the `sales_order_invoice_save_before` event to the invoice object and check for this flag, but `sales_order_invoice_pay` is better. At least if no third party modules didn't use `pay()` (no example, just my nightmare)

Comment: Good explain Sander

Comment: fyi - `sales_order_invoice_pay` doesn't necessarily mean the order has been fully paid (there may be items not yet invoiced).  If you need to check that the order is fully paid then you can use `$observer->getEvent()->getInvoice()->getOrder()->$order->getBaseTotalDue()` inside `sales_model_invoice_pay`.  `getBaseTotalDue()` returns the outstanding balance on the order--so a zero return indicates the order is 100% paid.

Answer (score 1):

use `sales_order_invoice_save_after` as this event is triggered many times, so to avoid unnecessary execution you can check the requesting `Module, Controller and Action` if the condition is met than execute it. you can do it by using below code in your observer file.

```
$request        = Mage::app()->getRequest();
$moduleName     = $request->getModuleName();
$controllerName = $request->getControllerName();
$actionName     = $request->getActionName();
if ($moduleName != 'customer' && $controllerName != 'accout' && $actionName != 'login') {
    //your observer code here

}
```

Comment: This is a bad idea because invoices can be created by a payment extension too. In this case the controller & action will be different