# Automatically send Invoice & Shipment using Observer

Tags: orders, email, invoice, sales-order, shipment

I am trying to automatically send shipment email when an invoice is created for an order but I can't get me code to work...

Here is what I have:

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Modulename_Invoicer>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Modulename_Invoicer>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <invoicer>
                <class>Modulename_Invoicer_Model</class>
            </invoicer>
        </models>
        <events>
            <sales_order_save_after> 
                <observers>
                    <sales_order_save_after_handler> 
                        <type>model</type> 
                        <class>invoicer/observer</class> 
                        <method>implementOrderStatus</method>  
                    </sales_order_save_after_handler>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_save_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

And Observer.php

```
<?php

class Namespace_Invoicer_Model_Observer
{

    public function implementOrderStatus ($event)
    {
        $order = $event->getOrder ();

        if ($this->_getPaymentMethod ($order) == 'ccsave') {
            if ($order->canInvoice ())
                $this->_processOrderStatus ($order);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    private function _getPaymentMethod ($order)
    {
        return $order->getPayment ()->getMethodInstance ()->getCode ();
    }

    private function _processOrderStatus ($order)
    {
        $invoice = $order->prepareInvoice ();

        $invoice->register ();
        Mage::getModel ('core/resource_transaction')
            ->addObject ($invoice)
            ->addObject ($invoice->getOrder ())
            ->save ();

        $invoice->sendEmail (true, '');
        $this->_changeOrderStatus ($order);
        return true;
    }

    private function _changeOrderStatus ($order)
    {
        $statusMessage = 'Order has been updated';
        $order->setState (Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE, true);
        $order->save ();
    }

}
```

I did follow this example [from Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-orders/automatically-invoice-ship-complete-order-in-magento/) if anyone has been able to get this to work please let me as I'm banging my head off of the desk...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  you said ,you want to send shipment mail after create Invoice.
For this ,you need change the event `from sales_order_save_after`  to `sales_order_invoice_register` which is better ...

**See more at**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661455/whats-the-event-name-when-you-create-a-new-invoice-in-magento

[Run method after capturing invoice](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/run-method-after-capturing-invoice)

Also Some issue in config.xml

```
<class>Namespace_Invoicer_Model_Observer</class>
```

Should be from `Namespace_Invoicer_Model_Observer` to `invoicer/observer`
Also Observer file implementOrderStatus() , $Order have wrong parameter

```
public function implementOrderStatus ($Observer)
{
    $order =$Observer->getEvent()->getOrder ();

    if ($this->_getPaymentMethod ($order) == 'ccsave') {

            $this->_processOrderStatus ($order->getIncrementId());

    return $this;
}
```

For Doing shipment on Order all items try below code ,so processOrderStatus() code should be

```
public function processOrderStatus($orderIncrementId){
$itemsQty = array();
$comment = null;
$email = true;
$includeComment = false;

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);
if ($order->canShip()){

$itemsQty = array();
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $itemsQty[$item->getId()] = $item->getQtyOrdered();
    }

     $shipment = $order->prepareShipment($itemsQty);

}
     $shipment = $order->prepareShipment($itemsQty);

        if ($shipment) {
            $shipment->register();
            $shipment->addComment($comment, $email && $includeComment);
            if ($email) {
                $shipment->setEmailSent(true);
            }
            $shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
            try {
                $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                    ->addObject($shipment)
                    ->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
                    ->save();
                $shipment->sendEmail($email, ($includeComment ? $comment : ''));
            } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                var_dump( $e->getMessage());
            }
           echo $shipment->getIncrementId();
        }

}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your input, I still cannot get this to work... I've updated my code above.

Comment: are you create invoice on  whole order items?? or you have doing partial invoice??

Comment: are you create invoice programmatically??

Comment: At the moment I am creating the Invoice through Admin, What I would like to do is when an invoice is created also create shipment at the same time and email to the customer...

Comment: now check again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Observer
{
public function implementOrderStatus($event)
{
    $order = $event->getOrder();

    if ($this->_getPaymentMethod($order) == 'ccsave') {
        if ($order->canInvoice())
            $this->_processOrderStatus($order);
    }
    return $this;
}

private function _getPaymentMethod($order)
{
    return $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
}

private function _processOrderStatus($order)
{
    $invoice = $order->prepareInvoice();

    $invoice->register();
    Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
       ->addObject($invoice)
       ->addObject($invoice->getOrder())
       ->save();

    $invoice->sendEmail(true, '');
    $this->_changeOrderStatus($order);
    return true;
}

private function _changeOrderStatus($order)
{
    $statusMessage = '';
    $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true);       
$order->save();
}
}
```

This is the section where you can change the code based on payment method:

For now its working for ccsave

```
if ($this->_getPaymentMethod($order) == 'ccsave') {
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I've added your code but the Shipment is still not being generated. FYI I am using PayPal and WorldPay as Payment method... See updated code.

Comment: I have updated my answer you will need to update the code as per your requirement